# Dropdown (with onChange) with custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, jquery, javascript, taxonomy

I have multi-select taxonomy field A. When one or more values are selected in A, I want to restrict the choices available in taxonomy field B.

So for example:

Two Taxonomies called

country - "USA", "Russia", "China"

city - "Chicago", "Moscow", "Beijing"

I want when user in taxonomy "country" choose value "USA" after that in taxonomy "city" show only "chicago".

Is it possible? And how can I do this using a JavaScript or jquery

Comment: Can you post the code for your multi-select?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing any code you could try the following

```
$('#IDofYourCountrySelectField').on('change', function() {
  //Code to update option values of city select field
});
```

or

```
$('#IDofYourCountrySelectField').change(function() {
  //Code to update option values of city select field
});
```